# How to turn Highchart scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have many columns to set in my chart, but the chart has width and label rotation fixed, so I need expand columns width to keep labels looks better.

Example:

```js
var labels = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5', 'Column 6', 'Column 7'];
Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: labels,
    labels: {
      rotation: 0
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  }, {
    data: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  }, {
    data: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }]
  
});
console.log('jia')
```

```css
#myChart {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use `HighStocks`, but I couldn't change `xAxis` categories to custom text, I think it's just for time.

How can I set fixed width to chart column and add scroll to the chart made with `HighCharts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include highstock.js and set max in `xAxis` for number of columns to appear

```js
var labels = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5', 'Column 6', 'Column 7'];
Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 30, //add for max y value(based on sum of series)
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: labels,
    labels: {
      rotation: 0
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 1, //max number of columns you want 1 means two column will show
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true //enables scrolling 
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  }, {
    data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  }, {
    data: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  }]

});
console.log('jia')
```

```css
#myChart {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, because I can't only truncate string, I need show the complete label description, sorry for other question and thank you so much!

Comment: why sorry Its good. highcharts requires commercial licence(commercial use) where as chart.js is MIT licence

Comment: Yes, but that's not a problem, the company has commercial licence, really thank you

Comment: How can I fix `yAxis` in max value? avoid `yAxis` values change when scrolling?

Comment: If I need set `yAxis` max value dynamically, I need calculate it by myself then set it to the property?

Comment: I tried to set `tickAmount` and `endOnTick: true` as showed in the documentation, but it's keep showing only the max of the range of value, maybe I will calculate and set it manually

Comment: you can use [load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) ,this is fired after chart is loaded can be used to update `max` value of `yAxis`. Its late night here may be tomorrow. Try first .if not add another question

Comment: But maybe I need calculate manually which is the max number to set into `max` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a high width on your chart container and add a **parent container** with a smaller width and set the `overflow-x` property to `scroll`

```js
var labels = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5', 'Column 6', 'Column 7'];
Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: labels,
    labels: {
      rotation: 0
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  }, {
    data: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  }, {
    data: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }]
  
});
console.log('jia')
```

```css
#myChart {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}
.chart-container{
  width:300px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <div id="myChart"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```